# Cache Pollution using System Call

Tags: linux, memory-management, operating-system, linux-kernel

Friends I want to study the effect of cache pollution due to operating system on an application's performance. 
For this I have written a small custom benchmark program.

```
1. malloc an array of size = l1 data cache-size
2. repeat ... sweep this array from start to end (hit-rate = 1.0)
3. *** perform a system call that thrashes l1 data cache ***
4. sweep the array once again (expected hit-rate = ~0.7 ---> 1.0)
```

The step 2 of the algorithm repeatedly reads the complete array. Hopefully the array would stay in the cache and hence result in a hit-rate of 1.

After I perform the system call, I try to read the cache once again. But I assume that the OS has evicted some cache lines belonging to the user.

As you can see, the program relies on the system call to evict many user data lines from the l1 data cache. How can I achieve this ??

I assume that the system call should be either file related or stream related.

Comment: Related: [FlexSC: Flexible System Call Scheduling with Exception-Less System Calls](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Soares.pdf) is a paper that has some measurements/simulations of lowered IPC *after* a system-call returns.  Also [Characterizing the Branch Misprediction Penalty](https://users.elis.ugent.be/~leeckhou/papers/ispass06-eyerman.pdf) might be relevant for understanding OoO exec after stalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effects on the L1 cache will vary from system call to system call. One method would be to loop through several different system calls and measure the impact of each (including, e.g. I/O-related calls like `write()`, where you can vary the size of a buffer, and thus the likely impact on the cache).

You will probably want to avoid system calls implemented as *vsyscalls* (e.g. `gettimeofday()`), as they don't require a switch into kernel-space. See [[1](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/), [2](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html)].

It sounds like you want to isolate the effects on the L1d, so another thing you might want to be careful about: in your step 2, after you've looped through your array, the L1i cache will have been populated. After your system call completes, it's likely that both the L1d *and* the L1i have been polluted, so you might also see the performance effects of i-cache misses.

To get better fine-grained measurements, you might be able to utilize hardware performance counters, depending on your architecture.

Comment: perfect ... i used open, write and close system call. i am trying to write the 32k array into a file after each iteration. But its effect was surprising ... the l1 data cache was showing lesser effect than the l1 instruction cache. Any ideas ?? I will re-post the exact stats describing the number of instructions per call, loads per call, etc. Anyways thanks for considering the post..

Comment: My immediate guess is that not a whole lot of kernel data is actually being touched (since is just writing from the user buffer), hence the small d-cache impact. I would try looking for a system call that manipulates a lot of kernel data structures---maybe something like `fork()` (although be aware of copy-on-write effects)

Comment: fwrite should typically write from the user-buffer to the kernel-buffer and then write it to the disk when the kernel buffers are empty. Is my understanding correct here ?? Does the kernel ever do a DMA straight from user- buffer to disk. I suppose not.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading Hennessy and Patterson - Thread-level Parallelism - OS and Multiprogramming Workload. The example shown to have L1-cache high on activity is the compilation of some benchmark code. Possibly, you can have some piece of code that can be compiled, and you spawn that compilation in step #3 to have the L1 cache modified. But yes, the L1i will get modified too.